# Plot confidence interval efficiently

Tags: stata

I want to plot confidence intervals for some estimates after running a regression model.

As I'm working with a very big dataset, I need an efficient solution: in particular, a solution that does not require me to `sort` or `save` the dataset. In the following example, I plot estimates for `b1` to `b6`:

```
reg y b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6

foreach i of numlist 1/6 {
   local mean `mean'  `=_b[b`i']' `i'   
   local ci `ci' ///
    (scatteri ///
    `=_b[b`i'] +1.96*_se[b`i']' `i' ///
    `=_b[`i'] -1.96 * _se[b`i']' `i' ///
    ,lpattern(shortdash) lcolor(navy)) 
} 
twoway `ci' (scatteri `mean', mcolor(navy)), legend(off) yline(0)
```

While `scatteri` efficiently plots the estimates, I can't get boundaries for the confidence interval similar to `rcap`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I would look directly at `coefplot` (_Stata Journal_) and then decide whether to write your own.

Comment: It's a detail, but `foreach i of numlist 1/6` is much less direct (and for what it's worth less efficient) than `forval i = 1/6`.

Comment: You can't recast `scatteri` to `rcap`: see `help twoway`.

Comment: Can or can't? I tried to add the option `recast(rcap)` after `lcolor(navy)` but it did not change anything. Could you post your solution?

Comment: I said can't and meant it. I still recommend `coefplot`; otherwise you need to make a dataset of the estimates. `scatteri` will not get you as far as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's token code for what you seem to want. The example is ridiculous. It's my personal view that refining this would be pointless given the very accomplished previous work behind `coefplot`. The multiplier of 1.96 only applies in very large samples.

```
sysuse auto, clear 
set scheme s1color 

reg mpg weight length displ 

gen coeff = . 
gen upper = . 
gen lower = . 
gen which = .  

local i = 0 
quietly foreach v in weight length displ {
   local ++i 
   replace coeff = _b[`v'] in `i'   
   replace upper = _b[`v'] + 1.96 * _se[`v'] in `i' 
   replace lower = _b[`v'] - 1.96 * _se[`v'] in `i' 
   replace which = `i' in `i' 
   label def which `i' "`v'", modify 
} 

label val which which 

twoway scatter coeff which, mcolor(navy) xsc(r(0.5, `i'.5)) xla(1/`i', val) ///
|| rcap upper lower which, lcolor(navy) xtitle("") legend(off)
```

Comment: I thought scatteri was faster than scatter/rcast. However, using a dataset of 1e8 observations, both our codes take around 30 sec, so there's actually no speed gain to use scatteri instead of scatter / rcast. Thanks